# 'Male'/'female' is to 'gender' as 'plural'/'singular' is to what?

Tags: hypernyms

'Male'/'female' is to 'gender' as 'plural'/'singular' is to ?

Comment: Number, as shown in [Collins](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/number):13. (Grammar) a grammatical category for the variation in form of nouns, pronouns, and any words agreeing with them, depending on how many persons or things are referred to, esp as singular or plural in number and in some languages dual or trial

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_number

Comment: Note, by the way, that 'male' and 'female' are not *genders* in the grammatical sense: the terms are 'masculine' and 'feminine'.

Answer (score 5):

Male/female is to gender as singular/plural is to **number**.

> - In linguistics, [grammatical number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_number) is a grammatical category of nouns, pronouns, and adjective and verb agreement that expresses count distinctions (such as "one", "two", or "three or more"). **In many languages, including English, the number categories are singular and plural**. Some languages also have a dual number or other arrangements.

Edit: credit to Edwin's and Josh's comments, which I hadn't read when I posted this answer.

Comment: English used to have dual pronouns for *us two* and *you two*, and it has, in fact, retained dual *both*.

Comment: I try to forestall answers to questions that are (at least borderline) ELL.

Comment: Masculine/feminine/neuter is to **gender**, as singular/plural is to **number**, as present/past is to **tense**, as first/second/third is to **person**, as positive/comparative/superlative is to **degree**, as  _he/his/him_ -- nominative/possessive/objective is to **case**. That's about it for [inflectional categories in English](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Inflection.pdf), though.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately for creativity, I believe the answer is "plurality."

Comment: I'm sorry I edited your answer by mistake. I've undone it.

Comment: Well, not quite. The [dictionary definitions](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/plurality) of plurality suggest that it only refers to multiple things, which loses the binary meaning the OP wanted. Furthermore, adding a definition and/or examples of usage with corresponding references would add credibility to your answers (in the future). Welcome to the ELU, btw :-)

Comment: @Lucky. Thanks. I'll try to be less trigger happy in the future.

Comment: Actually, when I read this question *plurality* was the first word that came to my mind as well, so I understand your line of thought. This is another reason why adding references is useful to the answerer as well as the others. But I do cheer your enthusiasm to participate :-)